# Is it possible to use the figure environment with the standalone package?

Tags: floats, standalone

I can not get `standalone` to work with figures; I get the error `Not in outer par mode`.

(The figure is in the included file.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update 2011/12/21

I now release `standalone` v1.0 which turns floats to non-floating environments automatically by default. Now you can use `figure` as normal inside `standalone` files. See the `float` option in the manual.

---

#### Original answer:

No, floats like `figure` and `table` environments are not supported with the `standalone` class or by the internally used `preview` package. The whole file is rendered as one box and there is not place where it could float to.

Just remove the environment and include your images or pictures as normal. Place the `figure` environment including the `\caption` in the main file and `\input` the standalone file there:

```
% inside the main file
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \input{somestandalonefile}%
   \caption{The caption text}\label{fig:abc}%
\end{figure}
```

If you want to have the caption inside the standalone for any reason load the `caption` or `capt-of` package and use `\captionof{figure}{<caption text>}`. You can put the whole thing in a `center` environment. However centering might not work properly in a standalone because of the cropping.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   % your image or picture code
   \captionof{figure}{The caption text}\label{fig:abc}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have standalone fit tight to the figure environment? That is, this demo: http://pastebin.com/327qEtf7 produces the image on the left, but the full page width of whitespace to the right of it. I want the output to be tight to the image.

Comment: @DavidDoria: Like mentioned the `figure` environment should not be in the `standalone` file, but be part of the main document. Your code seems to great a paragraph which is then `\linewidth` wide. This causes the white space on the right.

Comment: Even when I create a separate file with just the contents of the float environment: http://pastebin.com/H7BGE9fm a full page is output. My final goal is actually to crop the full figure of a subfig: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79877/crop-a-float-containing-subfigures-horizontally-with-preview-or-standalone-packa - it seems to almost work like that, but the subfig subcaption letters are misaligned - can you comment on that as well? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidDoria: Don't add empty lines after the content. They create a parapgraph break. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34590/2975 for an explanation. Note that the 'crop' option doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being crazy, but this: http://pastebin.com/0tKvPkGk is still producing a full page?

Comment: And with the answer here (that works): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79877/crop-a-float-containing-subfigures-horizontally-with-preview-or-standalone-packa/79925#comment171780_79925 - only one file is used. So I guess I don't understand the difference between using a separate "standalone" file and just using the 'standalone' documentclass in the main file?