# Nested standalone files with standalone package

Tags: nesting, standalone

Is it possible to nest files with the standalone package?  I have something like the following:

In A.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{B}
\end{document}​
```

B.tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \input{C}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

C.tex is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l l r r } 
    A & B & C & D
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}​
```

A and C compile fine, but when compiling B.tex I get errors starting with :

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

and complaining from there.

Is what I'm trying to do -- where A.tex includes B.tex includes C.tex -- possible?  Possible with floats?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It appears that once you fix your typos (`\usepackage` needs to be before `begin{document}`) and include the required packages in the main file, and replace using the article class this compiles, but fails with `standalone`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can nest `standalone` files, however, as with any other document which `\input`s `standalone` files you need to load the `standalone` *package* also in this case.

Another issue is that you can't use floats like `table` and `figure` environments in normal `standalone` files, because of the used `preview` mode used. You need either switch it off using the class option `preview=false` or redefine the `table` environment to not be a float.

```
% B.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\renewenvironment{table}{}{}% Ignore `table` environment in standalone mode.
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \input{C}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

If you have a `\caption` you should use:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}{\def\@captype{table}}{}
\makeatother
```

instead, otherwise you get an error.

#### Update 2011/12/21

I now release `standalone` v1.0 which redefines floats by defaults to work
inside `standalone` files. See the `float` option in the manual for more details. See also [Is it possible to use the figure environment with the standalone package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/is-it-possible-to-use-the-figure-environment-with-the-standalone-package/15416#15416)

Comment: This comment will be deleted shortly. I sent a bug report to your e-mail. `preview` environment of `standalone` class takes the following white spaces that makes the output no longer tight.

Answer (score 2):

Although this doesn't use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/standalone.html) package, I hope it will interest you.

I frequently use my own hack to have standalone documents that I can compile separately. I devised it before I came to know [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/standalone.html), and the only drawback that I haven't solved yet is that it doesn't behave very well in presence of subfolders.

## The file `a.tex`

Use `\input{include.sty}` (defined below) at the very top of the document, and directly `\begin{xdocument}` (note the `x`) and `\end{xdocument}` without any preamble.

```
\input{include.sty}
\masterdocumenttrue
\begin{xdocument}
\input{b}
\end{xdocument}
```

`\masterdocumenttrue` lets you know when the file passed to LaTeX on the command-line is the "master" document, and not a subdocument, so you can include conditionnaly stuff like the table of contents and bibliography by enclosing them in `\ifmasterdocument …\fi`.

## The file `b.tex`

Same thing, but no `\masterdocumenttrue` here.

```
\input{include.sty}
\begin{xdocument}
\begin{table}
  \input{c}
\end{table}
\end{xdocument}​
```

## The file `c.tex`

```
\input{include.sty}
\begin{xdocument}
\begin{tabular}{ l l r r } 
    A & B & C & D
\end{tabular} 
\end{xdocument}​
```

## The file `preamble.sty`

This file contains the pramble to use for all files.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{foo}
%\def\mycommand{bar}
```

## Step-by-step through `include.sty`

This file includes the preamble only for the "main" document (the one passed on the command-line to LaTeX), inserts `\begin{document}` when the first `\begin{xdocument}` is run, and inserts `\end{document}` when the fisrt `xdocument` is closed (thus the last `\end{xdocument}`) if your `xdocument`s are properly nested, and they should be.

Since we didn't use LaTeX's `\usepackage`, we need to change `@`'s catcode ourselves:

```
\makeatletter
```

If the macro `\nesteddocumentlevel` is undefined, then it's the first time `include.sty` has been included, so it does its job, but not the rest of the time:

```
\ifx\nesteddocumentlevel\undefined
\def\nesteddocumentlevel{0}
```

We avoid using an extra counter (there are only 255 of them) by providing a command to increment any macro, by putting it in a temporary counter just to increment it, and back into the macro afterwards:

```
\def\addtomacrocounter#1#2{%
  \bgroup%
  \@tempcnta=#1%
  \advance\@tempcnta #2%
  \expandafter\xdef\noexpand#1{\the\@tempcnta}%
  \egroup%
}
```

Build an easy-to-use macro `\ifdocumentlevel{level}{if-equal}{if-different}` to check the current inclusion depth:

```
\def\ifdocumentlevel#1#2#3{
  \edef\testnesteddocumentlevel{#1}
  \ifx\nesteddocumentlevel\testnesteddocumentlevel#2\else#3\fi%
}
```

Build the `xdocument` environment:

```
\newenvironment{xdocument}{
```

It increments the inclusion depth pseudo-counter:

```
  \addtomacrocounter{\nesteddocumentlevel}{1}
```

If we're in the top-level document, insert a `\begin{document}`

```
  \ifdocumentlevel{1}{
    \document% = \begin{document}
```

If we have a file named `main-header.tex`, it will be included at the beginning of the document passed on the command-line to LaTeX, that is before `b.tex`'s content when you compile `b.tex`:

```
    \IfFileExists{main-header.tex}{\input{main-header.tex}}{}
  }{}
```

If we have a file named `every-header.tex`, it will be included at the beginning of every (sub-)document, that is before `b.tex` and `c.tex`'s contents when you compile `b.tex`:

```
    \IfFileExists{every-header.tex}{\input{every-header.tex}}{}
}{
```

When running the `\end{xdocument}`, we define a `\maybeenddocument` macro, that will be `\expandafter`ed, and may output `\end{document}`, and include various footers.

If we have a file named `every-footer.tex`, it will be included at the end of every (sub-)document, that is after `b.tex` and `c.tex`'s contents when you compile `b.tex`:

```
  \IfFileExists{every-footer.tex}{\input{every-footer.tex}}{}
  \ifdocumentlevel{1}{

    If we have a file named `main-footer.tex`, it will be included at the end of the document passed on the command-line to LaTeX, that is after `b.tex`'s content when you compile `b.tex`

    \IfFileExists{main-footer.tex}{\input{main-footer.tex}}{}
```

When we're in the top-level document, we're going to output a `\end{document}`:

```
    \def\maybeenddocument{\enddocument}
  }{
```

But not the rest of the time:

```
    \def\maybeenddocument{}
  }
```

Pop one level of inclusion:

```
  \addtomacrocounter{\nesteddocumentlevel}{-1}
```

And place the possible `\end{document}` after the very last bit of code of `\end{xdocument}`. If we place it earlier, it will complain about unmatched `{`s, beacuse their matching `}` will be after the `\end{document}`, that is, in limbo.

```
  \expandafter\maybeenddocument%
}
```

When `include.sty` is included for the first time, we include the preamble. `preamble.sty` should contain everything between your \documentclass{…} and \begin{document}, without the \begin{document} itself.

```
\input{preamble.sty}
```

And create the `masterdocument` conditionnal. We need to escape its name with `\csname` and `\endcsname`, otherwise TeX thinks its a real `\if…`, matches it with the `\fi`, which belonged to the `\ifx\nesteddocumentlevel\undefined` at the top of this file, which in turn will have no matching `\fi`

```
\expandafter\newif\csname ifmasterdocument\endcsname\masterdocumentfalse
```

End of the code run when `include.sty` is included for the first time:

```
\fi
```

And restore the behaviour of `@`:

```
\makeatother
```

## Complete code for `include.sty`

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\nesteddocumentlevel\undefined
\def\nesteddocumentlevel{0}
\def\addtomacrocounter#1#2{%
  \bgroup\@tempcnta=#1%
  \advance\@tempcnta #2%
  \expandafter\xdef\noexpand#1{\the\@tempcnta}%
  \egroup}
\def\ifdocumentlevel#1#2#3{
  \edef\testnesteddocumentlevel{#1}
  \ifx\nesteddocumentlevel\testnesteddocumentlevel#2\else#3\fi%
}
\newenvironment{xdocument}{
  \addtomacrocounter{\nesteddocumentlevel}{1}
  \ifdocumentlevel{1}{
    \document% = \begin{document}
    \IfFileExists{main-header.tex}{\input{main-header.tex}}{}
  }{}
    \IfFileExists{every-header.tex}{\input{every-header.tex}}{}
}{
  \IfFileExists{every-footer.tex}{\input{every-footer.tex}}{}
  \ifdocumentlevel{1}{
    \IfFileExists{main-footer.tex}{\input{main-footer.tex}}{}
    \def\maybeenddocument{\enddocument}
  }{
    \def\maybeenddocument{}
  }
  \addtomacrocounter{\nesteddocumentlevel}{-1}
  \expandafter\maybeenddocument%
}
\input{preamble.sty}
\expandafter\newif\csname ifmasterdocument\endcsname\masterdocumentfalse
\fi
\makeatother
```