# Figure preview wrapper

Tags: diagrams, preview

How do I best preview my figures?
I have one file with this:

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{tikzpicture}  %if tikz
 ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \includegraphics{...}  %if eps
 \caption{...}
 \label{fig:..}
\end{figure}
```

and I can use it in my papers with `\input{...}`, but to preview my figure, I need some compilable wrapper like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \input{FIGURENAME}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to write this wrapper in a way, so it can be used for all my figures? or is there a better way to do this? shellscript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) *class* for your `tikzpicture` files and then use the `standalone` *package* in your main  document to ignore the preamble.
This way you can compile the picture alone and as part of an or multiple documents. In standalone mode the output file is automatically cropped to the picture size.

Each picture is in its own file which looks like:

```
% somepic.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,10); % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the main document:

```
% maindocumen.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}

% text ...

\begin{figure}
 \input{somepic}
 \caption{...}
 \label{fig:..}
\end{figure}

% text ...

\end{document}
```

I'm working on a new version which provides `\includestandalone` which is also able to include the PDF or EPS generated from the picture file instead of input the file.

Comment: Cool - this is just what I need. I can see, that you consider \begin{figure} and \caption{} to be part of the main doc and not the figure. I do not do doubt your reason, but why!?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: This has multiple reasons. You might want to insert the same picture into multiple documents (e.g. paper, presentation & thesis) with different captions or using a different form like a non-float or subfigure. Then, `figure` is a float and `standalone` uses `preview` by default which removes all white space around it, but can't handle floats. It stores the content in a box which doesn't work with floats. See also my recent answer to [Nested standalone files with standalone package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30784/31829#31829).

Comment: It is not working - what am I doing wrong. pdf is ok. dvi is partly outside page - shown with xdvi. ps from dvips is empty - shown with mac preview. .... Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549), pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010), Preview Version 5.0.3 (504.1). This is dvips(k) 5.99, xdvik version 22.84.16 (Xaw toolkit) Libraries: kpathsea version 6.0.0, T1lib version 5.1.2

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: This seems to be a problem of the underlying `preview` package. Try with `preview=false` as class option in the pictures files. This won't crop the white space but avoid this things.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: I now released v1.0 of `standalone` which provides a new option `crop` as alternative to `preview`. It should fix certain problems with the `preview` option. There is also a `float` option to allow floating environments inside subfiles (but they are turned to non-floats in standalone mode). Both new options are turned on by default in v1.0.

Comment: Thanks. Since I went pdf, I have not had any problems with standalone. - on the contrary it has been extremely useful. One thing that I am missing though is a way to use relative paths in standalones( http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38412/import-input-pgfplots-with-relative-paths ), but it is hardly a standalone issue.