# Simultaneously compiling many content source files included into one styled file

Tags: compiling

I am writing five or so texts which serve as course notes. I have one master file `Style.tex` into which I include the various bodies of these course notes. The reason I do it like this is because it's easier to make sure I am using the same style and notation across several documents. However, I have to edit `Style.tex` to specify which body text I would like to include. It would be nice if I could compile all notes simultaneously and generate pdfs for each set of notes with one command.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX is able to produce only one PDF for compilation; you probably need some sort of script for this task. What operating system are you using?

Comment: The standard way to make sure a collection of documents share a common style is to start them all `\documentclass{mylocalclass}\begin{document}.....\end{document}`  and put all the shared code in the document class file.

Comment: Following up on David's comment, if you don't feel comfortable tackling your own local class file, you can put the common code into a style file and `\usepackage{mylocalstyle}`.

Answer (score 7):

I think that your present approach in the reverse of what must be done. If you don't want the hassle to write your own class (as suggested by David Carlisle) or even package,
which is somehow tricky, you have the **standard solution** as follows :

First you put in a `mystyle.sty` file ( without `\documentclass[]{}` nor `\begin{document}.....\end{document}` ) all the `\usepackage{}` and manual settings  that must be shared (and only this).

Secondly you reorganize your courses files as regular tex files (one per course) like this :

```
 \documentclass[<options>]{report} % or another class you prefer
 \input{mystyle.sty}
 % here put settings or info specfc to to this course, as \title{} aso>
 \begin{document}
   <body text>
 \end{document}
```

You then can compile them  while sharing all the content of `mystyle.sty`, and need no never multi-editing. Furthermore, if you change something in this `mystyle.sty`, you will be able to transfer the change by a simple recompilation of all the ourses file without edit them (a script could be useful for this last step if you have to many  courses...)

**EDIT** a very simple batch file for DOS/Windows would be:

```
@echo off
FOR %%C IN ("*.tex") do (
echo "compiling"  %%~C
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %%~dpnC > all.log
FOR %%A IN ("aux","out","nav","log","toc","thm") do IF EXIST %%~dpnC.%%A (del %%~dpnC.%%A) 
)
pause
```

of course :

- `"*.tex"` could be refined in eg `"course*.tex"`
- the `pdflatex` line could be customized according to your aim, o better replaced by another script which builds all including BiBTeX biblio, indexes aso.
- the list of deletion can be extended in a straightforward way.

Comment: Why not also include the documentclass in mystyle.tex?

Comment: @ Aditya : just a question of taste ! To ensure by inspection that you have a regular latex file with the mandatory `\documentclass{}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. The key point was to reverse the logic of the inputs.

Comment: @psychoticpsychiatrist I apologize, I have read your post to quickly: even if the naming 1.tex aso is not a good idea your script does create the file as long as mine assumes that they already exist.

Answer (score 4):

I just made a batch script for this myself (for Windows).

```
@ECHO off
FOR /L %%X IN (1,1,5) DO (
IF EXIST %%X.tex (
TYPE start.tex > temp.tex
TYPE %%X.tex >> temp.tex
TYPE stop.tex >>temp.tex
pdflatex -synctex=0 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -jobname=%%X temp
)
)
FOR /L %%X IN (1,1,5) DO ( DEL %%X.aux & DEL %%X.log & DEL %%X.out)
PAUSE
```

Place `1.tex`, `2.tex`, ... , `5.tex` (the name of your files) in a directory with this script (named `whatever.bat`). Make a `start.tex` file (in the same directory) which looks like

```
\documentclass{someclass}
some preamble
\begin{document}
```

and a stop.tex file (in the same directory) containing

```
\end{document}
```

What the script does is, checks if a file `1.tex` exists, and if so, writes `start.tex` to `temp.tex`, include the text in `1.tex` in `temp.tex`, writes `stop.tex` to `temp.tex` and compiles `temp.tex` with the name `1.pdf`. Then moves on to `2.tex`, and so on.

The line before the `PAUSE` command removes auxiliary files. You may want to remove this line.

You might also want to change the `pdflatex` options.

If you get more documents, change the (or both) `for` loop to `(start,step,stop)`, that is `(1,1,10)` for 10 documents.

Please not that this is my first batch script ever and i strongly recommend you to take copies of what you've written before you use it. If you're on Linux, perhaps someone can write a `bash` script (I don't have access to Linux right now).

Edit: Please use jhor's one instead. Mine is, as pointed out, a beginner's one. For me, the numbering was important (solution files in a textbook, attached in pdf to specific questions which could then be thrown around at will), hence the simple for-loop which gets the work done.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define the content file to be compiled on the command line.

So, if the file below is saved as `Style.tex`, then to compile the body of `DocumentA` you would use:

```
pdflatex "\def\MyFile{DocumentA}\input{Style.tex}"
```

This eliminates any need to change the `Style.tex` file.

### Notes:

- Although this is a separate topic, I think worth mentioning: If you also desire to be able to compile `DocumentA` directly, then you should also have a look at [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone). An example is at [Nested standalone files with standalone package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30784/nested-standalone-files-with-standalone-package)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Your custom style settings, either included from a .sty
%% or defined here.

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\MyFile
    \input{\MyFile}
\else
    \PackageError{Style.tex}{"MyFile" was not defined.}{}
\fi
\end{document}
```