# How to use figure inside a exercise environment?

Tags: floats, environments, exercises

Trying to use figure inside an `Exercise` environment (`exercise.sty`) gives me "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode."

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{exercise}
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[title={foo}, label=ex1]
A tough question.
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}[ref={ex1}]
A smart answer.

\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[totalheight=0.2\textheight]{couetteFlowFig1.png}
   \label{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

I see in [Is it possible to use the figure environment with the standalone package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/is-it-possible-to-use-the-figure-environment-with-the-standalone-package) that there was a similar problem with a different package, and that limitation in the package was eventually handled.  It appears the same limitation exists in the `exercise` environment.  Is there a work around that allows for inclusion of a figure with that package, or a different way of including a figure when using this package?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is *no* requirement to place an image (using `\includegraphics`, say) inside a `figure` environment. The `figure` environment is merely a floating placeholder. So, you can just put your image inside a `center` environment to centre it on the page, and even add a caption using `\captionof` from the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{exercise}% http://ctan.org/pkg/exercise
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[title={foo}, label=ex1]
A tough question.
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}[ref={ex1}]
A smart answer.

\begin{center}
  %\includegraphics[totalheight=0.2\textheight]{couetteFlowFig1.png}
  \rule{150pt}{100pt} \par
  \captionof{figure}{This is a figure caption.}
  \label{fig:ex1}
\end{center}
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I've replaced the image with a rectangular block to simulate the image, but it will work with `\includegraphics` as well (for which you will require `\usepackage{graphicx}` - the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).

The problem originates from inserting `figure` inside `Exercise`. Or, more generally, a float inside a non-floating (or restrictive) environment. Therefore, removing the floating environment enables the compilation to succeed.

Comment: Martin scharrer has a new package called `mwe` now @ Werner. I like it as it will save me from typing all those details regarding rectangular block.

Comment: This gave me hypcap=true warnings (and odd link placement), but otherwise worked very nicely.  I was able to avoid the hypcap and link placement issue by using an alternate caption syntax:


\newcommand{\imageCentered}[4]{%
\begin{center}%
   \captionsetup{type=figure}%
   \includegraphics[totalheight=#4\textheight]{#1}%
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
\end{center}%
}

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use `float` package as follows. In this case `figure` environment works fine together with `\caption`. The code is quite similar to @Werner's answer, with only a few lines changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{exercise}% http://ctan.org/pkg/exercise
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[title={foo}, label=ex1]
A tough question.
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}[ref={ex1}]
A smart answer in Fig. \ref{fig:ex1}.

\begin{figure}[H]
  %\includegraphics[totalheight=0.2\textheight]{couetteFlowFig1.png}
  \rule{150pt}{100pt} \par
  \caption{This is a figure caption.}
  \label{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```