# How to detect if in an exercise environment?

Tags: graphics, floats

I found in [How to use figure inside a exercise environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55338/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-exercise-environment) that I can't use begin{figure} ... \end{figure} in an exercise environment.  I also found situations where avoiding the use of such floats can cause other trouble (see: [In memoir environment, the chapter heading placement gets messed up if a too big figure gets placed on next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55832/in-memoir-environment-the-chapter-heading-placement-gets-messed-up-if-a-too-big)).

The logical thing to do would be to have a programatically check for an Exercise or Answer environment, perhaps doing something like the following:

```
\newcommand{\imageFigure}[4]{%
  IF I AM IN A FLOAT-UNSUPPORTED environment % ie: Answer or Exercise
    \begin{center}%
       \captionsetup{type=figure}%
       \includegraphics[totalheight=#4\textheight]{#1}%
       \caption{#2}%
       \label{#3}%
    \end{center}%
  ELSE
    \begin{figure}[htp]%
       \centering%
       \includegraphics[totalheight=#4\textheight]{#1}%
       \caption{#2}%
       \label{#3}%
    \end{figure}%
  ENDIF
}
```

The question [How can I detect if I'm inside or outside of a float environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27172/how-can-i-detect-if-im-inside-or-outside-of-a-float-environment) does something similar, and using that idea I thought I might be able to use the \theExercise and \theAnswer counters, but it appears that their values can be non-zero even when not in these environments.

I imagine that it would be possible to set and clear a flag before and after using either of these environments respectively.  Perhaps there is already such a flag already internally in the exercise.sty implementation.

Presuming this is possible, how would the pseudocode predication in the figure generation command above be modified to actually work?

Comment: You can use `\@currenvir` to check for the current environment. See [Command behavior depending on current environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39738/5764).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`figure` and other floating environments give an error if they are inside any kind of box (as it stops them floating) so if `\ifinner` is true you don't want to float.

```
  \ifinner
      non float version
   \else

      float version

   \fi
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` to set a boolean to be `true` inside the `Exercise` and the `Answer` environment and then test inside your command for that boolean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{exercise}

\newbool{InExerciseOrAnswer}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Exercise}{\booltrue{InExerciseOrAnswer}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Answer}{\booltrue{InExerciseOrAnswer}}

\newcommand*\test{\ifbool{InExerciseOrAnswer}{I'm in :)}{I'm not :(}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
 \test
\end{Exercise}
\test

\begin{Answer}
 \test
\end{Answer}
\test

\end{document}
```

[image]