# How to make table floats work with preview/standalone environment?

Tags: tables, floats, standalone, preview

Couldn't make a table float work inside the preview environment:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{25pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{testing}
\label{tab:testing}
\end{table}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

gives error "Not in outer par mode". The manual of preview mentions a "floats" option, but adding it makes no difference. I know that making a table "float" don't make much sense in a single preview page, I just want them to become non-float and stay in the place where it's defined and show up in the preview.

And then I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/is-it-possible-to-use-the-figure-environment-with-the-standalone-package/15416#15416) question. It says that standalone package would work. But I couldn't get it to work either:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{testing}
\label{tab:testing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

gives error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item". And even if it works, it raises a serious problem, that is, it occupies the documentclass but I must use KOMA-Script. By the way, I use xelatex, don't know if it matters.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I think I have mentioned in the post that I know what a "float" means and that it does not make "much" sense. But it does make some sense: I use preview for, literally, preview. So every element in the document should show up in the preview so I can "preview" it. And for a table float the proper way of show up is to become a non-float and stay at where it's defined. This is exactly what [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/is-it-possible-to-use-the-figure-environment-with-the-standalone-package/15416#15416) post says standalone is supposed to do. Then after the preview, if I comment out the preview package or make it inactive, every thing should work in the normal way again (table floats float normally, etc). So I'm not asking for a method of making a table float sticky, but how to make it show up in preview/standalone environment.

**Solution**:The solution turns out to be

```
\documentclass[preview,class=scrartcl,fontsize=20pt]{standalone}
```

This will automatically turn table floats into non-float while retaining the original document class. Also see Jesse's answer for a clever but a little more sophisticated solution.

Comment: table is a float and using it like this doesn't make sense. Use `float` package and make `\begin{table}[H]` or don't use table. To have captions use `capt-of` package with it `\captionof` macr.

Comment: @HarishKumar It does make some sense. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

In the link you have posted, the author of the `standalone` package mentions that floats are now possible in `standalone` and that one should have a look into the manual on the `float` option.

Doing this for you, I got the following code, which should work for you.

**Edit** I also included the required option to get the `scrartcl`-look and the desired fontsize.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[%
    ,float=false % this is the new default and can be left away.
    ,preview=true
    ,class=scrartcl
    ,fontsize=20pt
    ]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{testing}
\label{tab:testing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Original Answer**

You should not use floating environments in the `standalone` class, as it makes no sense. Labels make no sense either. I would recommend to use the `caption` package for your caption (as this package is often used in normal articles as well) and to wrap you table in a minipage.

[image]

```
% arara: pdfatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\minipage{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{testing}
\endminipage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Floats in preview do make some sense. Please see my updated question. And so do labels. I sometimes test hyperlinks in preview, if they works in preview, they works outside preview, too. And you need links when reading a really long preview page.

Comment: @kawing-chiu Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update, it's quite close now. So how can I retain \documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrartcl} when using standalone as a documentclass?

Comment: @kawing-chiu Sorry, I don't understand that. You have to choose between document classes. Or is Jesses approach, what you want? He ha got kind of a switch. If you wan't, I can program a real switch, but when do you want to switch the document class?

Comment: Basically, what I want is to "preview" a document. Originally, in my question, the table float doesn't work in the preview. Now, using \documentclass[preview]{standalone}, the table float works, but the fontsize is different since the documentclass is changed. So what I want is just a perfect preview of the original document.

Comment: I've figured it out. \documentclass[preview,class=scrartcl,fontsize=20pt]{standalone} will do the trick. The standalone package has the ability to use a "underlying package". Maybe you can include this in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to define an non-float environment for `tablehere`, but still capable of caption ability without using package.

**Update:** `tablehere` is changed to the `table`, but renew it to non-float when preview mode is used. So  remove all % below for preview mode.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{25pt}
%
%\makeatletter
%\renewenvironment{table}
%{\def\@captype{table}}
%{}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\begin{preview}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{testing}
\label{tab:testing}
\end{table}

%\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

**Original Answer:**

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother
```

Code

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{25pt}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\begin{tablehere}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b\\
\hline
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{testing}
\label{tab:testing}
\end{tablehere}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It kind of works, but what I really want is to make it work under preview/standalone without the need to change the original float (see my updated question). Can it be done?

Comment: @kawing-chiu -- please see my update.