# How can you create a vertical timeline?

Tags: moderntimeline

So far I have this, which half gets the job done, but I really wanted a slightly better looking and more descriptive timeline. Really I wanted to be able to write more than one line for each new addition to the timeline.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\foo}{\hspace{-2.3pt}$\bullet$ \hspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}

\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tabular}{r |@{\foo} l}

1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook\\
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\

\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

I really need something that works in the same way the horizontal timeline does when using the chronology package.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136244/automatically-setting-one-node-after-the-other-in-tikz) is is what you want?

Comment: See http://ctan.org/pkg/harnon-cv. This is for a CV but you could use the code for just the timeline part.

Comment: Was just thinking to create such a timeline from scratch. Nice idea. I'd like to explore the idea of having two colums, and the vertical timeline as a separator with entries alternating between the left and right column.

Comment: Off-topic: Please write `AT\&T`, not `AT and T`.

Comment: I am also looking for a timeline but I find that yours, OP, is the best actually!

Comment: This is a form of itemised list rather than a timeline, since the dates are not separated in proportion of the time gaps.

Answer (score 86):

With a vertical time-line and multilined cells — and a caption on the left side of the table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook\\
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* (3/12/18)

Here  is a code to  satisfy the request of smaller bullets, an initial bullet and an arrow on the time-line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\tiny\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}
\newcommand{\bfoo}{\raisebox{2.1ex}[0pt]{\makebox[\dimexpr2\tabcolsep]%
{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\tiny\textbullet}}}%
\newcommand{\tfoo}{\makebox[\dimexpr2\tabcolsep]%
{\color{LightSteelBlue3}$\boldsymbol \uparrow $}}%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\begin{longtable}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
 \caption{Timeline} \\[-1.5ex]
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex] 
 \multicolumn{1}{c!{\tfoo}}{}& \\[-2.3ex]
1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook\\
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
 \multicolumn{1}{c!{\bfoo}}{}&
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very nice! :o)

Comment: I just want to point out the rather obvious point that shoud someone wish to use a similar code within the __standalone__ class, to produce a self-contained timeline (with a view to inserting it into multiple documents, for instance, with includegraphics), one needs to remove the floating {table} environment. I hope this saves the google some work.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work with "longtable" so that it spans across multiple pages?

Comment: @vrbatim: I'll try to see that.

Comment: @vrbatim:  It works like a breeze with `longtable`.

Comment: @Bernard: Can you please share a MWE for longtable?

Comment: @cosmicraga: It needs not be changed except for the environment (longtable rather than tabular). This requires the longtable package.

Comment: This is beatiful: just a question, is it possible to add a smaller textbullet at the bottom of the timeline and an arrow on top of it? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: @luciadefinetti: Please  see my additional code. Does the result befit you?

Comment: Is it possibile to remove the "Table 1" string from the caption, leaving only "Timeline"?

Comment: @zar: Very easily: you only have to declare a new caption format in the preamble, say `\DeclareCaptionFormat{nolabel}{#3}`, and replace the \captionsetup{…} in the above code with `\captionsetup{format=nolabel, font=blue}`.

Comment: @Bernard thank you. I have another problem: I am not able to use your macros with the longtable package. I have tried with a simple substitution tabular->longtable, but it doesn't work. It compiles correctly, but the table is on one page only, and the last lines are out of the margins.

Comment: @zar: I don't understand. My answer has an edit to satisty somea new requirements, including a longtable, and  as far as I remember, it worked.  Try to see if you coded your long table in the same way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that I should have used your edited version. Now everything works, thanks again.

Comment: Your're welcome! Are you OK with the really small bullets?

Answer (score 48):

An attempt without any package (except for add some color, obviously):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\ytl[2]{
\parbox[b]{8em}{\hfill{\color{cyan}\bfseries\sffamily #1}~$\cdots\cdots$~}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\bullet$}\vrule\quad \parbox[c]{4.5cm}{\vspace{7pt}\color{red!40!black!80}\raggedright\sffamily #2.\\[7pt]}\\[-3pt]}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Timeline of something.}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}
\color{gray}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\ytl{1947}{AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones}
\ytl{1968}{Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'}
\ytl{1971}{Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator}
\ytl{1973}{First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper}
\ytl{1978}{Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy}
\ytl{1981}{Osborne 1 Portable Computer}
\ytl{1982}{Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop}
\ytl{1983}{TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC}
\ytl{1984}{Psion Organiser Handheld Computer}
\ytl{1991}{Psion Series 3 Minicomputer}
\bigskip
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: when attempt compile "\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}" give error... Help :(

Comment: @LuisRivera ... A standalone class  with   a `table` float?  Very bad idea. Remove `\begin{table}`and `\end{table}`. But anyway, why a standalone? This is not a tikz image that take time to compile ...

Comment: or use `float=false`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171983/11604

Comment: I couldn't understand, what is the difference between this and most other answers that the rows here are centred vertically but not in them?

Comment: @Martund Personal preferences? The question did not establish any requirement in this regard and the answers are very different approaches, so  why would they have to give the same result?

Comment: @Fran, I never said they should give the same result. I am asking for the difference in LaTeX code that accounts for this.

Comment: This one is really self-explanatory, just if it had an arrowhead, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 36):

I have posted posted an answer before which realizes a vertical timeline for another question, but I think this may fit your needs. You can make multi line entries for each timeline entry and multiple entries for each year. Note that it may need some tweaking here and there to fit your needs.

Also note that I'm posting this answer as a community wiki entry because I have posted this same answer before. If you want to give credit for it, please do it at the original question: [High level macros and environments based on Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154558/8844).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,%
    paperheight=297mm,%
    tmargin=7.5mm,%
    rmargin=7.5mm,%
    bmargin=7.5mm,%
    lmargin=7.5mm,
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}

\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]{%
    % #1 is startyear
    % #2 is tlendyear
    % #3 is yearcolumnwidth
    % #4 is rulecolumnwidth
    % #5 is entrycolumnwidth
    % #6 is timelineheight

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
            align=left,%
            text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
            node distance=10mm,%
            anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
        \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
            draw,%
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
            postaction={decorate},%
            shorten >=0.4pt]

        \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{timeline}{1900}{1990}{2cm}{2.5cm}{5cm}{12cm}
\entry{1903}{Wilbur and Orville Wright fly the first powered airplane}
\entry{1914}{Assassination of Franz Ferdinand}
\plainentry{1917}{The October Revolution}
\entry{1928}{Discovery of Penicillin}
\plainentry{1929}{Stock Market Crash of 1929}
\entry{1941}{Attack on Pearl Harbor}
\plainentry{1944}{D-Day}
\entry{1945}{The Bombing of Hiroshima}
\plainentry{1947}{Creation of Israel as a Jewish State}
\entry{1963}{US president John F. Kennedy assassinated in Dallas}
\entry{1969}{The Moon Landing}
\plainentry{1989}{Fall of the Berlin Wall}
\end{timeline}

\bigskip

Text from: A Brief History of LaTeX http://www.xent.com/FoRK-archive/feb98/0307.html

\smallskip

\begin{timeline}{1974}{1985}{2cm}{7cm}{10cm}{0.45\textheight}
\entry{1974}{Donald Knuth stops submitting papers to the AMS because ``the finished
product was just too painful for me to look at''.}
\entry{1977}{Knuth begins his research on typography.}
\entry{1978}{Knuth delivers an AMS Gibbs Lecture entitled Mathematical Typography to the AMS membership at its annual meeting.}
\entry{1979}{Digital Equipment Corporation and the AMS jointly publish Knuth's TeX and METAFONT: New Directions in Typesetting.}
\entry{1980}{The first draft of Spivak's Joy of TeX is announced in TUGboat, vol. 1, no. 1.}
\entry{1982}{Spivak announces AMS-TeX at the joint math meetings.}
\entry{1982}{Version 0 of Spivak's Joy of TeX is released.}
\entry{1982}{Knuth releases dvitype, a model DVI driver.}
\entry{1983}{Lamport writes a LaTeX manual, the earliest known LaTeX manual in existence.}
\entry{1984}{Addison-Wesley publishes Knuth's The TeXbook, destined to become the definitive TeX reference.}
\entry{1984}{Lamport releases version 2.06a of the LaTeX macros.}
\entry{1985}{The Computer Modern (CM) fonts replace the American Modern (AM) fonts in TeX.}
\entry{1985}{Patashnik releases BibTeX version 0.98 for LaTeX 2.08. [``BibTeX 1.0'', TUGboat, vol. 15, no. 3, pp. 269--274, Sept. 1994.}
\end{timeline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a great bit of code and very useful. However there is an error in it. Try doing the same timeline twice in a row (use your first example) and you will see that the second time around the year labels (except the first and last) disappear. I think the node names must somehow be retained between runs.

Comment: Can this be extended to add months, as well as years?

Comment: @AndrewWatson I guess you would have to add a third argument to the `\entry`environment and then modify the nodes... did you ever implement this?

Answer (score 32):

Here is another example with TikZ matrices.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

%% Code by Claudio:
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197447/221452
%% Uses code by Andrew:
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\makeatletter
    \let\matamp=&
    \catcode`\&=13
    \def&{%
        \iftikz@is@matrix%
            \pgfmatrixnextcell%
        \else%
            \matamp%
        \fi%
    }
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline

\tikzset{
    description/.style={column 2/.append style={#1}},
    timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
    timeline color=red!80!black,
    timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
    use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
    use timeline header=false,
    add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
    add bottom line=false,
    timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
    timeline title={},
    line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
    line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
    \setcounter{lines}{1}%
    \stepcounter{vtml}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
        column 2/.style={anchor=west},
        text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
        row sep=1ex,
        column sep=1em,
        #1
    ]
        \matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}

        \path[timeline color st]
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);

        \foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
            \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick]
            (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
                \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
        }

        \ifvtimelinetitle%
            \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
                ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);

            \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
                at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west)
                {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};
        \else%
            \relax%
        \fi%

        \ifvtimebottomline%
            \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
            ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
        \else%
            \relax%
        \fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{vtimeline}[description={text width=7cm},
        row sep=4ex,
        use timeline header,
        timeline title={The title}]
        1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\endlr
        1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
        1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
        1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
        1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
        1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
        1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
        1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
        1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
        1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
    \end{vtimeline}

    \begin{vtimeline}[timeline color=cyan!80!blue, add bottom line, line offset=2pt]
        1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\endlr
        1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
        1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
        1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
        1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
        1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
        1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
        1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
        1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
        1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
    \end{vtimeline}

\end{document}
```

In the first environment the header is activated. The result is:

[image]

In the second environment the header is not set up, but a line is added at the bottom of the timeline with a custom offset (default `4pt`). In addition, the color is different and no constraints have been put on the description width:

[image]

Comment: This looks and works great. How would one go about adding a horizontal line below the timeline as well as above?

Comment: @PacificOrion: Thanks! Actually it is not complicated: I'll try to give you a feedback on this in the next days.

Comment: @PacificOrion: I just revised the answer to include a line below the timeline.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Sir how to save this tex file separately and then call it with an input or include command

Comment: @jsbibra: just copy the corresponding part in the preamble (from the call to environ all the way down before the document evironment). Then input this new file in your document.

Comment: Awesome ! How can you increase the width of the second column ?

Comment: @3isenHeim: sure, you can try the usual width options within `column 2/.style`

Answer (score 20):

Here is another variation using tikz to produce:

[image]

As you said that you wanted to be able to have multiple lines for each entry in the timeline I have given them a `text width` of 60mm and positioned the different entries below each other (and the years to the left of them). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\newcommand{\foo}{\hspace{-2.3pt}$\bullet$ \hspace{5pt}}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{year}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.5,%
           year/.style={draw=red,text=blue,fill=yellow!20,shape=ellipse,inner sep=2pt},
           description/.style={rectangle,align=center,text width=60mm,anchor=west},
           timeline/.style={->,thick,red!50}]

    \foreach \year/\desc [count=\y] in {%
       1947/AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones,%
       1968/Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook,%
       1971/Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator,%
       1973/First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper,%
       1978/Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy,%
       1981/Osborne 1 Portable Computer,%
       1982/Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop,%
       1983/TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC,%
       1984/Psion Organiser Handheld Computer,%
       1991/Psion Series 3 Minicomputer%
       } { \ifnum\y=1 \node[description](\y){\desc};
           \else\node[description,below=1ex of \z](\y){\desc};
           \fi
           \node[year](y-\y) [left=of \y] {\year};
           \ifnum\y>1\draw[timeline] (y-\z)-- (y-\y);\fi
           \global\let\z=\y% for drawing from last node
       }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have used the counters `\y` and `\z` to dynamically draw the edges between the years...I feel like there should be a more efficient tikz-y way of doing this...

Comment: Nothing quite like a friendly unexplained down-vote....

Answer (score 13):

I haven't looked at the [`chronology`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronology) package but can a simple table as the following do?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Timeline.}
\label{tbl:1}
\begin{tabular}{r l}
  \toprule
  1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
  1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
  1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
  1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
  1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\\
  1981 & Osborne~$1$ Portable Computer\\
  1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
  1983 & TRS-$80$ Model~$100$ Portable PC\\
  1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
  1991 & Psion Series~~$3$ Minicomputer\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Here we have table~\ref{tbl:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Compare your table with the OP's...

Answer (score 13):

Here is a modified version of `chronology.sty`, `chronology-vert.sty`. Note that this is not at all well-tested and is liable to break. In particular, the timeline is ***not*** boxed or resized, so the user must ensure that things fit appropriately.

## *Caveat emptor...*

```
%% Modifications copyright 2015 Clea F. Rees
%% Code from origfile copyright 2011 Levi Wiseman (see below)
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%%
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clea F. Rees.
%%
%% This work consists of the file chronology-vert.sty.
%%
%% chronology-vert.sty is a derived work under the terms of the LPPL.
%% The original file, chronology.sty, is supplied with chronology. A
%% copy of chronology including an unmodified copy of chronology.sty
%% is available from
%% http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronology.
%%
%% The main modifications made to this file are as follows:
%% - This notice is added.
%% - The file is renamed.
%% - The timeline is created as a vertical, rather than horizontal
%% progression.
%% - The timeline is not boxed or resized. Hence, it is up to the user
%% to ensure that things fit appropriately.

% based on chronology 2010/6/12 v1.0 Horizontal timeline
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%
\ProvidesPackage{chronology-vert}[2015/05/02 v1.0 Horizontal timeline]
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{step}\newcounter{stepstart}\newcounter{stepstop}
\newcounter{yearstart}\newcounter{yearstop}\newcounter{deltayears}
\newlength{\ystart}\newlength{\ystop}
\newlength{\unit}\newlength{\timelineheight}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifchronology@star
\newenvironment{chronology}{%
    \@ifstar{\chronology@startrue\chronology@i*}{\chronology@starfalse\chronology@i*}%
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\def\chronology@i*{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\chronology@ii*}{\chronology@ii*[{5}]}%
}%
\def\chronology@ii*[#1]#2#3#4{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\chronology@iii*[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}}{\chronology@iii*[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}[{#4}]}%
}%
\def\chronology@iii*[#1]#2#3#4[#5]{%
    \newif\ifflipped%
    \ifchronology@star%
        \flippedtrue%
    \else%
        \flippedfalse%
    \fi%
    \setcounter{step}{#1}%
    \setcounter{yearstart}{#2}\setcounter{yearstop}{#3}%
    \setcounter{deltayears}{\theyearstop-\theyearstart}%
    \setlength{\unit}{#5/\thedeltayears}%
    \setlength{\timelineheight}{#4}%
    \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstart}{\theyearstart+\thestep-mod(\theyearstart,\thestep)}%
    \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstop}{\theyearstop-mod(\theyearstop,\thestep)}%
    \addtocounter{step}{\thestepstart}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]%
          \draw [|->] (0,0) -- (0,-\thedeltayears*\unit-\unit);%
          \foreach \y in {1,...,\thedeltayears}%
              \draw[yshift=-\y*\unit] (-.1\unit,0) -- (.1\unit,0);%
          \addtocounter{deltayears}{1}%
          \foreach \y in {\thestepstart,\thestep,...,\thestepstop}{%
              \pgfmathsetlength\ystop{(-\y+\theyearstart)*\unit}%
              \draw[yshift=\ystop] (-.3\unit,0) -- (.3\unit,0);%
              \ifflipped%
                  \node at (0,\ystop) [left=.2\unit] {\y};%
              \else%
                  \node at (0,\ystop) [right=.2\unit] {\y};%
              \fi%
          }%
}%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\event}[3][e]{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\ystop{(#2-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
    \ifx #1e%
        \ifflipped%
            \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5]%
                (0,-\ystop) circle (.2\unit)%
                node[opacity=1,rotate=30,right=.5\unit] {#3};%
        \else%
            \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5]%
                (0,-\ystop) circle (.2\unit)%
                node[opacity=1,rotate=30,left=.5\unit] {#3};%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \pgfmathsetlength\ystart{(#1-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
        \ifflipped%
            \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5,rounded corners=.2\unit]%
                (-.2\unit,-\ystart) rectangle%
                node[opacity=1,rotate=30,right=.5\unit] {#3} (.2\unit,-\ystop);%
        \else%
            \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5,rounded corners=.2\unit]%
                (-.2\unit,-\ystart) rectangle%
                node[opacity=1,rotate=30,left=.5\unit] {#3} (.2\unit,-\ystop);%
        \fi%
    \fi}
\newcommand{\decimaldate}[3]{(#1-1)/31/12+(#2-1)/12+#3}
\endinput
```

The example file provided with the `chronology` package produces the following if `chronology-vert` is used instead (and the vertical spacing removed):

[image: vertical timelines]

Applying this to the original example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chronology-vert}
\begin{document}
  \begin{chronology}*[5]{1940}{1995}{20cm}
    \event{1947}{AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones}
    \event{1968}{Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook}
    \event{1971}{Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator}
    \event{1973}{First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper}
    \event{1978}{Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy}
    \event{1981}{Osborne 1 Portable Computer}
    \event{1982}{Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop}
    \event{1983}{TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC}
    \event{1984}{Psion Organiser Handheld Computer}
    \event{1991}{Psion Series 3 Minicomputer}
  \end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: vertical timeline]