# Creating a textual timeline

Tags: chronology

I am trying to create a timeline and looking for the appropriate package, if such exists. I have learnt about the `chronology` package, but this seems to provide a horizontal chronological graphical line. Rather, I am looking to create a textual timeline, something like a list with years and descriptions.

Comment: What about the `description` environment in that case?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline.  This question with its answers provide several very nice vertical timelines.