# How can I make a (beautiful) vertical timeline for LaTeX beamer?

Tags: presentations, chronology

I am currently using `\usepackage{enumitem}` and  a list to make a horizontal time line on a single slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Plan for 2015/2016}
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2cm]
            \item[12/2015] First Week: Do abc
            \item[] Second Week: do def
            \item[01/2016] \,
            \item[02/2016] Do foo in bar
            \item[03/2016] Do foo in bar
            \item[04/2016] Do foo in bar
            \item[05/2016] Write something about unicorns
            \item[06/2016] Write something about unicorns
            \item[07/2016] Write something about unicorns
            \item[08/2016] Timelines can look awesome
            \item[09/2016] Timelines can look awesome
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

While this looks ok, but I think it could be nicer:

[image]

To make this fit the StackOverflow criteria:

- Is there a package for vertical timelines?
- Can I add a line with dots (12/2015, 02/2016, 05/2016, 08/2016) on the left of the list / between the dates and the text?

Comment: I am pretty sure, the TikZ mafia here will show a way ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer is just jealous that we can do things [like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215082/). {Mine but I've deliberately chosen a community wiki answer. Unfortunately, it is a horizontal timeline. I don't do vertical ones ;).

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline) help? There are a number of different answers there. [Note that I apparently lied about not doing vertical timelines. I revise that to: I don't do beautiful vertical timelines.]

Comment: @cfr: Nice! I will have a look at it tomorrow, but it looks VERY much like what I had in mind.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate because, if that question is very close, it is probably better to ask a new question if you need to ask about modifying something or whatever (since you've confirmed that you want something which is at least going to be very like what's offered there).

Comment: @cfr: Yes, [Bernards answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/5645) was what I was looking for. Thank you :-)