# Including BODY in self-defined environment

Tags: environments

This is a follow up question to [Create array of specific counter values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292208/create-array-of-specific-counter-values) and [Using self-defined fields in NewEnviron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292257/using-self-defined-fields-in-newenviron).

I want to use the function `mtadd` that fills the array `mtarr` depending on the value of `lines`, inside of the environement `myenv` that creates the line between the columns. To do so, I have to include the body definded outside. But this produces the error `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`, apparently related to the redefinition of `&` starting at line 10, which I don't entirely understand (taken from Claudio Fiandrino in [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline)).
Commenting out `\BODY` leads to the correct line, but the function `mtadd`doesn't work and thus `myarr` stays empty.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{charter}

\makeatletter
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\makeatletter
\def&{\iftikz@is@matrix
  \pgfmatrixnextcell
  \else
  \matamp
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{envcount}
\setcounter{envcount}{0}

\newcommand*\myarr{}
\newcommand{\mtadd}{
\ifx\myarr\empty
\edef\myarr{\arabic{lines}}
\else\edef\myarr{\myarr,\arabic{lines}}
\fi}

\tikzset{description/.style={
  column 2/.append style={#1}
 },
 line color/.store in=\lcolor,
 line color=white!80!black,
 line color st/.style={fill=\lcolor,draw=\lcolor},
}

\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][]{%
\def\myarr{}
\setcounter{lines}{1}
\stepcounter{envcount}%
\BODY
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
 column 2/.style={anchor=west},
 #1
]
\matrix(myenv\theenvcount)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}
\path [line color st]
($(myenv\theenvcount-1-1.north east)!0.5!(myenv\theenvcount-1-2.north west)$)--
($(myenv\theenvcount-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(myenv\theenvcount-\endmtx-2.south west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\names{{"Katie","Frank","Laura","Joe","Peter","Jens","Carolin","Anna","Steph","Stef"}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
test &  now\mtadd\endlr
test &  \foreach \i in \myarr {%
     Name \i: \pgfmathparse{\names[\i]}\pgfmathresult, }\endlr
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't change anything if I put the `\BODY` in the figure or above, just if I place it before the definitions of the counters, they don't apply. Sorry, if I don't understand entirely what you mean. I'm completely new to laTex coding.

Comment: Let's start over.  As I understand it, you want to count the number of names and fill an array with (1,2,3,...} to match.

Comment: What I want is the function `\mtadd` to fill the array `\myarr` only with specific line numbers of my choice. The array `\myarr` is supposed to be used in the figure to create a set of points. What's behind, is a generalization of the timeline in the post of Claudio Fiandrino in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline. I want to have different spacings between the entries of one timeline, sometimes 3 lines, somtimes 1 ... .

Comment: Thank you. Actually the way I did it already works, if I create the array by myself, just the more elegant way of using a function like I'm trying here doesn't work. ... due to this strange error.

Comment: Anyhow, I will think about using the measure of te box instead, even though I have doubts at the moment that this could be inculded into the method I've chosen so far. About other methods, I don't know any alternative that would create such a nice looking timeline as this one did.

Comment: The error isn't strange.  Expanding \BODY  includes the & character, which causes an error if the parser isn't expecting it.

Comment: So is there a way to prevent this and still get it running? I mean, I just need the function `\mtadd` to work inside the environment.