# How to create comparative timelines in LaTeX?

Tags: templates, datetime, chronology, timeline

I want to create comparative timeline as below:

```
Date   | Event 1 | Event 2 | Event 3 | Event 4 |
================================================
DDMMYY |  text   |  text   |  text   |  text   |
------------------------------------------------
DDMMYY |  text   |  text   |  text   |  text   |
------------------------------------------------
DDMMYY |  text   |  text   |  text   |  text   |
------------------------------------------------
```

so that data will be sorted chronologically and I can compare events.
[image]

another example
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please, tell and show to us, what you try to do so far.

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline/196808)