# Timeline that uses a longtable environment

Tags: tables, longtable, timeline

I am struggling in using longtable environment for the answer posted in following thread.

[How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the 'Dynabook\\
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have neither loaded nor used `longtable` in that example....

Comment: Off-topic: Please write `AT\&T`, not `AT and T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{longtable}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}

% header and footer information
\caption{Timeline}\\
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
\endhead

\addlinespace[1.5ex]
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

% body of table
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to make such a timeline without using tables so that I can use multicolumn page format and which will continue to the subsequent pages?

Comment: @cosmicraga - As you've noticed, the `longtable` environment cannot be placed into a multicolumn environment. However, the `xtabular` environment (provided by the `xtab` package) does have this ability. Be aware, though, that the syntax of the `longtable` and `xtabular` environments aren't identical.

Comment: I have posted this as a new question. I will be grateful if you give me a MWE. Thanks.

Comment: @cosmicraga The idea is that you provide an MWE in the question and we help you to modify it to solve a problem or add a feature - not that somebody start writing your document from scratch without knowing anything about it.