# Table spanning multicolumn and multipage using xtabular

Tags: tables, xtab, timeline

I would like to have a timeline where if the length is larger than the page, it will first continue as a second column in the same page, and if required, will continue to the next page's first column, and so on ....

Following is a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336164/timeline-that-uses-a-longtable-environment/336168?noredirect=1#comment824250_336168) which is based on [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline) answer but this solution is not exactly what should be best for my requirement. In the first link, it has been suggested that this can be achieved using xtabular.

Following is what I have achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\topcaption{My List}
\xentrystretch{-0.15} % height of table in each page
\begin{xtabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}}
% header and footer information
%\addlinespace[1.5ex]

\bottomrule
% body of table
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

What I could not do:

1. Align the table at the top in both the columns
2. Making table heights equal (or almost equal) in both the columns
3. Adding (or Removing from top) the top horizontal border in the subsequent continuation of table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? Do you pass the option `twocolumn` to the document class, or do you achieve the two-column look by some other means? How wide are the columns?

Comment: I would like to use this as a personal journal. The document will consist of both one column and multiple column timelines as needed.

Comment: I think, in a 'book' class, passing the option 'twocolumn' will serve the purpose. Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adapting the machinery used in the answer to your earlier question to an `xtabular` setting, using the `book` document class in two-column mode? Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have edited the question with what I have achieved so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Provide `\tablefirsthead`, `\tablehead`, and `\tablelasttail` instructions in addition to `\topcaption`.
- In particular, use `\tablehead` to create a quasi-caption for all text columns but the first.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, ragged2e}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}
% header and footer information
\topcaption{My List} \label{tab:timeline}
\tablefirsthead{\toprule}
\tablehead{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\textsc{Table \ref{tab:timeline}}, cont'd}\\[0.6ex]
        \toprule}
\tablelasttail{\bottomrule}
\xentrystretch{-0.15} 

\begin{xtabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
1947 & AT\&T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\\
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\\
1971 & Busicom `Handy-LE' Calculator\\
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\\
1978 & Parker Bros.\ Merlin Computer Toy\\
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\\
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\\
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\\
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\\
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\\
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```