# Toggle bullet point in vertical timeline

Tags: tables, timeline

I'm quite happy with the time line presented in [Timeline that uses a longtable environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336164/timeline-that-uses-a-longtable-environment)
However, I'd like to skip some of the bullet points.

I tried using a boolean toggle, but it seems like the logic is not used inside the tabular environment.

Is there a way to get more control of when the bullet points appear?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{accentcolor}{RGB}{ 250, 150, 10 }

\newbool{time_bullet}
\setbool{time_bullet}{true}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{accentcolor!80}\makebox[0pt]{
        \ifbool{time_bullet}{
    \LARGE\textbullet\setbool{time_bullet}{false}}
{\setbool{time_bullet}{true}}
}\hskip-0.0pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}\ifbool{time_bullet}{\setbool{time_bullet}{false}}{\setbool{time_bullet}{true}}}

\newcolumntype{F}{<{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lF}
    1 & Test\\
    2 & Test \\
    3 & Test
\end{tabular}
\foo{}
\foo{}
\foo{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what the desired outcome is, But, I suspect it is a grouping issue: see if using `\global\setbool` instead of just `\setbool` does what you want.  Also, you may need to replace thetwo insteances of `{` at the end of a line with `{%` so you don't end up with spurious spaces.

Comment: Indeed, setting the bool values globally fixed the problem! This snippet was just supposed to help me understand how I can control those bullet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter Grill pointed out, the boolean values need to be set globally.

Thus using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{accentcolor}{RGB}{ 250, 150, 10 }

\newbool{time_bullet}
\setbool{time_bullet}{true}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{accentcolor!80}\makebox[0pt]{%
        \ifbool{time_bullet}{%
             \LARGE\textbullet\setbool{time_bullet}{false}}
{\setbool{time_bullet}{true}}
}\hskip-3.2pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}\ifbool{time_bullet}{\global\setbool{time_bullet}{false}}{\global\setbool{time_bullet}{true}}}

\newcolumntype{F}{<{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lF}
    1 & Test\\
    2 & Test \\
    3 & Test
\end{tabular}
\foo{}
\foo{}
\foo{}
\end{document}
```

works perfectly fine with the result

[image]