# Fancy vertical timeline

Tags: tables, timeline

I'd like to have a timeline as similar as possible to this **with the addition of being able to add a logo at the left of each textbullet**, but I've got no clue at all:

[image]

Thanks very much in advance for any help :)

p.s. I've stumbled upon this answer ([How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline)) but I don't how to modify it to get what I want!

Comment: Have you checked out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline#196808) yet?

Comment: @lucia de finetti That is always the case with almost everyone of us :) But we start somewhere right? could you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @chrisma you anticipated me :) Raaja basically the answer that I and chrisma linked it's all I've got!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as `tikzpicture`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 3mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   dot/.style = {circle, draw=white, very thick, fill=gray,
                 minimum size=3mm},
   box/.style = {rectangle, text width=62mm,
                 inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=1mm,
                 font=\sffamily\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 on chain},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={box}]
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-1
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
\node { From september 2010 to september 2013   \\      % A-3
        \textcolor{gray}{Industrial design}     \\
        Universidad Antonio de Nebrija, Madrid} ;
    \end{scope}
\draw[very thick, gray, {Triangle[length=4pt)]}-{Circle[length=3pt]},
      shorten <=-3mm, shorten >=-3mm]           % <--- here is adjusted additional arrow's 
    (A-1.north west) -- (A-3.south west);
\foreach \i [ count=\j] in {2013,2010,2006}
    \node[dot,label=left:\i] at (A-\j.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! How can I add a bit of space above the small dot and below the arrow?

Comment: @luciadefinetti, i do not understand your ask. do you like to discontinue line? or make it longer? or shorter?

Comment: Just longer with more space between the arrow and the first entry and also more space between the last entry and the small dot. Thank you!

Comment: @luciadefinetti, done. see edited answer.