# Tables on adjacent pages have different positions when using longtable

Tags: longtable, timeline

I want to draw one timeline for my study. After google searching, I find the style answered by @Bernard in [a post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline/196808). I tried to copy/paste it to [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kqxxcrzsssrr) and see whether it suits my purpose. However, I encountered one issue with latex longtable: tables on adjacent pages have different positions. As my account cannot comment on his answer, so I repost my question here. Hope the author or someone can help me figure out the underlying problem.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you are using book or some other document class with `twoside` which is causing the margins to change based on whether the page is odd or even.

Comment: Confirming what @DonHosek said, the first line of your overleaf file is `\documentclass[a4paper, ` **twoside** `, 11pt]{report}` Note this is unrelated to `longtable` your entire document will have wider margins on the outer edges. Use `oneside` if you want all pages to have the same layout.

Comment: Yes, thanks @David Carlisle and DonHosek. You are right. After I remove twoside or change it to oneside, it works as expected. Great, thanks again.