# Connected item list with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize, timeline

I'm trying to draw a list of items, not unline `itemize`, where the dots are all connected by a vertical line. In other words, what I'm aiming for is a kind of vertical timeline, but without dates. In fact, I have started by -stealing-, I mean, taking inspiration, from the TikZ answer in [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline), but I have to major problems:

1. list items go beyond page limit, while they should remain inside the page, like an actual `itemize`
2. List items currently do not accept `\par` and `\\`, while I would need to support these

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\def&{%
  \iftikz@is@matrix%
  \pgfmatrixnextcell%
  \else%
  \matamp%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
    
\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\tikzset{
  description/.style={column 2/.append style={#1}},
  timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
  timeline color=red!80!black,
  timeline color st/.style={fill=orange,draw=green},
  line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
  line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
  \setcounter{lines}{1}%
  \stepcounter{vtml}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%column 1/.style={anchor=east},
    column 1/.style={anchor=west},
    text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
    row sep=1ex,
    column sep=1em,
    #1
    ]
    \matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}

    \foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
      \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10pt, line width=.75mm]
      (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at
      ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.west) + (-1ex, 0)$){};
    }

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw[blue, line width=1mm] (vtimeline\thevtml-c-1.center) -- (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\endmtx.center);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vtimeline}%[row sep=4ex]
  This is a very long sentence, hopefully it will generate a new line, otherwise I will have to keep writing nonsense on and on and on and on\endlr
  Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
  Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
  First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
  Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
  Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
  Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
  TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
  Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
  Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
\end{vtimeline}

\end{document}
```

[image: my output]

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know that the colors I chose are ugly, in fact they are temporary and just for testing purposes. Moreover, I would really like to be able to make this work with TikZ because this is the first step of something a bit more complicated that I would not know how to do without TikZ.

Comment: Sounds like you can use `tikzmark` to remember the positions of bullets and connect them after all texts are properly broken into lines and pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I don't know if this idea might suffice.  The problem is that the comma is a list separator; you cannot use it in an item as it is, but with curly brackets, i.e. `{,}` (see the example).

Note that the distance between the items is the same.  You can control it through `node distance` values.  Moreover, you can use `\\` to break lines inside an item.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\linedlist}[1]{\noindent%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={node distance = 6ex and 1.5ex}]
    \node[anchor=west] at (0, 0) (S-0) {};
    \tikzmath{ integer \nbPoints; }
    \foreach \s [count=\i from 1, evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i-1)}]
    in {#1}{%
      \node[below=of S-\j.south west, anchor=west, align=left] (S-\i) {\s};
      \node[left=of S-\i,
      draw=red, circle, shade, ball color=red,
      outer sep=0, inner sep=.65ex] (N-\i) {};
      \pgfextra{\xdef\nbPoints{\i}}
    }
    \foreach \i [parse=true, evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i+1)}]
    in {1, ..., \nbPoints -1}{%
      \draw[thick] (N-\i) -- (N-\j);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\linedlist{
  If you can't explain it to a six year old{,}
  you don't \\
  understand it yourself.,
  The important thing is to not stop questioning.,
  Look deep into nature{,} and then you will \\
  understand everything better.,
  A happy man is too satisfied with the present \\
  to dwell too much on the future.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel N, this seems a very good answer! You showed me a smart way to use `\foreach` that I did not know and would have never thought of. As for the outcome, however, I will need to use commas in my text, and I need to have more control on the nodes, as they are central in what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I modified the answer slightly.  You can use commas, but they must appear as `{,}`, otherwise they represent separators in the loop list.  As for the *mode control on the nodes*, you should be more specific.  It's too vague.  Anyway, in the code, the nodes have each a name.  You can use them afterwards as you wish.  But try to give an example of what you need.

Comment: A question: How do you intend to use the list, inside a `tikzpicture` environment or in paragraph mode?  Accordingly, the definition of the list will be different...

Comment: Hi @Daniel N, I took so long to accept your answer because I had to find a workaround for `parse=true` that is not supported by my version of TikZ (and unfortunately I'm not able to update.) In any case, this solution does what I asked and leaves a lot of control on the item nodes, so it's good enough for me `:)`

Comment: Hi @Pier Paolo.  I'm glad you will use it!  `parse=true` is there for avoiding the computation `\nbPoints -1`.  But it can be done inside a `\tikzmath` before the `\foreach`.