How to add these markers in a CV command?
I am creating a LaTeX document in which I am using a custom education entry called '\educ'. However, I would like to apply the markers on left side (as illustrated in the image). I think the better package to reach that result is Tikz. It follows my working code.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25} % 1.25 line spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5.5pt}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\educ}[3]{
  \needspace{3\baselineskip}
  {\large\textbf{#1}}\\
  {#2}\\
  {\itshape#3}
}


\begin{document}


\section*{Formal Education}

\educ{Title}{University}{Location}\\
\educ{Title}{University}{Location}


\end{document}


Thank you!

maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline could give you a starting point

Here is a possibility using TikZ, though I suspect there may be a better way using tcolorbox which would have the advantage of being able to break across pages. (This solution will not work if the list goes across a page break.)
The idea is to place the center of a \textbullet 2mm to the left of the left text edge for each title. This is done by inserting a box of 0 width containing the bullet and 4mm of space into the \educ macro.
Then tikzmark is used in a new univs environment, which marks the beginning and end of the section. A vertical line is theb drawn shifted left 2mm to pass through the bullets, starting at the first bullet and ending at the bottom of the last entry.
Note that you need to compile twice.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25} % 1.25 line spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5.5pt}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\educ}[3]{
  \needspace{3\baselineskip}
  {\noindent\makebox[0pt][c]{\textbullet\hspace{4mm}}\large\textbf{#1}}\\
  {#2}\\
  {\itshape#3}
}

\newenvironment{univs}{\pgfmark{A}}
    {\pgfmark{B}\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
        {\draw[thick] ([shift={(-.2,-1.1\baselineskip)}]pic cs:A) to ({\tikztostart} |- {pic cs:B});
    }
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Formal Education}

\begin{univs}
\educ{Title}{University}{Location}\\
\educ{Title}{University}{Location}
\end{univs}

\end{document}


Awesome! That works perfectly! Really thank you.
